# node js: Why module.exports = tesdf() from require is executed only once, inside get request

Tags: node.js, get, require

index.js

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
       require('./test.js') // after repeated request is not executed
       console.log("test")//after repeated request is  executed
       next();
    })

app.listen(8097)
```

test.js

```
function tesdf(){console.log("Gtest test", ind++); }
module.exports = tesdf()
```

How to make a function called again.
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you are exporting a file, you export the function, classes or variables. Here you are exporting the result of `tesdf()` function. To solve this just export it like:

```
function tesdf(){console.log("Gtest test", ind++); }

module.exports = tesdf
```

Also you should not use `required('./test.js')` inside of the get request because everytime some client request for that end point, the method is going to load the file. e.g

```
let test = require('./test.js');
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
       test();//Call the method
       console.log("test")//after repeated request is  executed
       next();
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Exporting a module in NodeJS turn it singleton, so an option to make it not singleton is to create different instance:

**test.js**

```
function tesdf(){
    console.log("Gtest test", ind++); 
}

module.exports = tesdf;
```

**index.js**

```
new (require('./test.js'))();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to export function without running, example in your case:

```
module.export = testdf
```

Before export in this way, import in a variable and run.

```
const testdf = require('./test.js')
testdf()
```

Answer (score 1):

**test.js**

```
function tesdf() {
    console.log("Gtest test", ind++); 
}
module.exports = tesdf;
```

**index.js**

```
var test = require('/path/to/test.js');
test();
```